# How does java differentiate Callable and Runnable in a Lambda?

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I got this little code to test out `Callable`. However, I find it pretty confusing how the Compiler could know if the Lambda is for the Interface Callable or Runnable since both don't have any parameter in their function.

IntelliJ, however, shows that the Lambda employs the code for a Callable.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executorService.submit(() ->{
            System.out.println("Starting");
            int n = new Random().nextInt(4000);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(n);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                System.out.println("Finished");
            }
            return n;
        });
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns a result, which Runnable doesn't, so it's a Callable.

Comment: The key phrases in the language spec are "void compatible" and "value compatible".

Comment: @Michael that's a simplistic explanation: you can use some lambdas which return values as runnables (e.g. `() -> Integer.valueOf(0)`), in which case the return value is discarded.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's an expression lambda, which OP is not using, and the rules are different. You can't write the keyword `return` and have the result be ignored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the documentation of ExecutorService which has 2 `submit` methods with one parameter:

- [`submit(Callable<T> task)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) using [`Callable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) which has method [`call()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call--) returning `T`.
- [`submit(Runnable task)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) usnig [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) which has method [`run()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run--) returning nothing (`void`).

Your lambda gives an output, returns something:

```
executorService.submit(() -> {
    System.out.println("Starting");
    int n = new Random().nextInt(4000);
    // try-catch-finally omitted
    return n;                                      // <-- HERE IT RETURNS N
});
```

So the lambda must be `Callable<Integer>` which is a shortcut for:

```
executorService.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        int n = new Random().nextInt(4000);
        // try-catch-finally omitted
        return n;  
    }}
);
```

To compare, try the same with `Runnable` and you see it's method's return type is `void`.

```
executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...  
    }}
);
```

Comment: confusing: "**three** `submit` methods with one parameter" but you only listed 2...(did you mean 2, since I believe there are only 2 with 1 parameter)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: It's a typo. I meant to list all the 3 `submit` methods, however then I recognized that only 2 make sense and left "3" accidentally. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmmm, this gives me mixed feelings. I'm glad we can use the shrothand syntax but when things become too indirect I feel like I'm not in control of what I'm writing.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference in the signature is that a `Callable` returns a value while a `Runnable`does not. So this example in your code is a `Callable`, but definately not a `Runnable`, since it returns a value.